# PHP Doctrine2 ORM "orm:generate:entities"

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I want generate new "Banner" entity class:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate:entities --generate-annotations="true" Entity/Banner
```

but I have this error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Entities destination directory
>   'Entity/Banner' does not exist.

Comment: you found solution? =)

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is the next.

`php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities`

You can see the docs in this [page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#display-help-information)

But maybe your problem is other, like the directory does not exist.
Did you try like this?

`vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate:entities --generate-annotations="true" Banner`

Use tab key to autocomplet the command, maybe that can help